# GotoMeeting - prevent session recording

Tags: display, recording, gotomeeting

I am conducting GotoMeeting to conduct online meetings and I have disabled the recording option. I would like to know if there is anyway to prevent the participants use any screen recording software.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr Probably not.**

I highly doubt that there are implementations in place to mitigate the risk of MUC participants recording a GoToMeeting session with a program like FRAPS (as an example), simply because you - the facilitator does not have control over the participant's systems.

Even if you're using a program like ESXi to manage VMs in-house, an individual can still deploy prepackaged, portable applications which facilitate both audio, and video recording.

---

What you CAN do is:

- Ensure that all discussions within the GoToMeeting session follow a predefined code of conduct
- Require the signing of a Non-Disclosure Agreement (NDA) with participants

Comment: Thanks - I was expecting the same, but still wanted to make sure of it.